# MIT-Scratch adding/removing language features

Tags: mit-scratch, block-programming

I am seeking a way to allow my non-tech users to specify a workflow and execute it (if anyone is interested, I want them to specify and execute test cases). Visual programming seems a good way to go.

Can I modify the Scratch IDE to remove some categories (such as sound, motion, etc), and add some of my own? Ditto for individual keywords (obviously, I then need to handle new keywords).

I *have* Googled, but the answer is not immediately apparent.

---

[Update] I have just found Google's [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/)

> Blockly was influenced by [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/), which in turn was influenced
>   by [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), which in turn was influenced by [StarLogo](http://education.mit.edu/projects/starlogo-tng).

It looks very promising. Especially when it says

> - Exportable code. Users can extract their programs as JavaScript,    Python, PHP, Dart or other language so that when they outgrow Blockly 
>     they can keep learning.
> - Open source. Everything about Blockly is    open: you can fork it, hack it, and use it in your own websites.
> - Extensible. Make Blockly fit with your application by adding custom    blocks for your API and remove unneeded blocks and
>     functionality.

One possible snag is that it is browser based, but if my management don't like that, then I can create a dummy Windows based app consisting of little but a TWebBrowser component.

I will investigate and report back - unless someone else posts an acceptable answer first.

Comment: And four years later the question gets a drive-by downvote, with no explanation given. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your initial question is: no. You can't customize Scratch, or not to the extent that you seem to ask/want.

That said, look at:

- custom blocks.
- scratch extensions.
- variants like *snap*
- using scratch's source code in squeak to make your own variant.
- other systems inspired from scratch, like appinventor and blockly.

Only the first two are compatible with the scratch web site.

A word on the site: depending on your purpose with Scratch, the exchange between users is a powerful part of scratch. Check how cooperation is supported, like the *backpack*. There's also a [good wiki](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_Wiki) that documents much of the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have discovered that https://code.google.com/archive/p/blockly/  can do what I want.